# UILabel with Translucent/Blurry Background View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UILabel` that I created on Storyboard. Actually it has a white background, but I would like to make it transculent. Is it possible somehow? It has only one background related property the `backgroundColor`, so I don't have any idea how should I implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make blurry background view in iOS 8 you can use UIVisualEffectView and UIVisualEffect:

```
UIVisualEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame;
[blueEffectView addSubview:*your label*];
[self.view addSubview:self.blurEffectView];
```

For < iOS 8 there is another option. You can use apple class "UIImage+ImageEffects.h". The logic is the same, but before you need to make screenshot, so it's looks like this:

```
- (void)applyBlur
{
    UIImage *screen = [self captureScreenInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *blur = [screen applyDarkEffect];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    imageView.image = blur;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (UIImage *)captureScreenInRect:(CGRect)captureFrame 
{
        CALayer *layer;
        layer = self.view.layer;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
        CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame);
        [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenImage;
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the target is iOS 7-8, so I'cant use it, but it's really good to know this solution, thanks.

Comment: I tried this and it just gives me a table view with a gray background

Answer (score 0):

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Plus I think you need to set opaque=NO on the view's layer if you want content underneath the view to show through.

Comment: Tried this, and it makes the background transparent. @DuncanC I'm using the label in a table cell, it has an image view underneath.

Comment: So if you only want it partly transparent, set your background color to a color with an alpha value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @DuncanC Cool, now it's transparent. Is there any solution to make it blurry?

Comment: @bushiko As I know there is no native bluring view until iOS8

Comment: I've been off doing development in Yosemite. I learned the API for blurred, translucent views there, but what is it in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to support iOS 7-8 you could use [FXBlurView.](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)It works really great on both and you can use it with Storyboards. Also if you want to take advantage of the Xcode 6 IBDesignable Classes, you could enable the ability to configure the view through the Storyboard like this.

**FXBlurView.h**

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface FXBlurView : UIView

+ (void)setBlurEnabled:(BOOL)blurEnabled;
+ (void)setUpdatesEnabled;
+ (void)setUpdatesDisabled;

@property (nonatomic, getter = isBlurEnabled) IBInspectable BOOL blurEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isDynamic) IBInspectable BOOL dynamic;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable NSUInteger iterations;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable NSTimeInterval updateInterval;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat blurRadius;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *tintColor;
@property (nonatomic, weak_ref) UIView *underlyingView;

- (void)updateAsynchronously:(BOOL)async completion:(void (^)())completion;

@end
```

**Note:** Even though FXBlurView works fine on iOS 8, I would recommend you to use the native UIVisualEffect & UIVisualEffectView, as suggested by @gronzzz, for iOS 8, since those classes are designed to do exactly the same with low performance cost.

[Ray Wenderlich iOS 8 Visual Effect Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)